# How use visualize Gaussian mixture model's clusters for multi dimensional data in Scikit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have seen the Scikit-Learn example of [Gaussian mixture for clustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture). In this example (and other examples of this model), it looks the data always has two dimensions:

```
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=10, color=colors[y_pred])
```

I use the following script ( X actully has more than 2 columns),

```
clf = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
clf.fit(X)
y_pred = clf.predict(X)
colors = np.array(list(islice(cycle(['#377eb8', '#ff7f00', '#4daf4a',
                                 '#f781bf', '#a65628', '#984ea3',
                                 '#999999', '#e41a1c', '#dede00']),
                          int(max(y_pred) + 1))))
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=10, color=colors[y_pred])
plt.show()
```

How can I visualize the clusters and data points?